# Does Canonical have plans to build UI Toolkit APIs for the D programming language

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml

There are APIs for C++, JavaScript and even Go. `D Programming Language` makes a good candidate for building `Ubuntu Next` apps and less complex compared to C++ IMO. It has good C++ bindings capability + `(Modelings Power, Native Efficiency and Convenience)`. It will really help build more apps if a D API is added. There is also a [QML bindings](https://github.com/filcuc/dqml) for D with a number of underground Qt bindings in progress and many [packages and bindings](http://code.dlang.org). I hear some community members are set to tackle the Vulkan API once it is released.

Answer (score 2):

Why would Canonical? Ubuntu is a community driven operating system and unless Canonical is going to focus on creating apps in D themself QML, HTML5 and C++ will do.

> I hear some community members are set to tackle the Vulkan API once it is released.

So the community should create an API/toolkit for D ;)

[dlang.org](http://wiki.dlang.org/The_D_Programming_Language) would be a good place to start. They have [DWT](https://github.com/d-widget-toolkit/dwt) (D widget toolkit) and several other [tools](http://wiki.dlang.org/List_of_GUI_Libraries).

Comment: Of-course D can build Ubuntu apps with tk, gtk, dwt, QML, ... currently and I don't expect Canonical to use D as their primary language in place of C++. I only ask `if they have considered in their plans` to add a `D API` as in the case of Go, as I made it `clear` above. I went forward to justify why I think D makes a good candidate to be `added`.  Therefore IMO, you have deviated from my question @Rinzwind :)